# Ambiguous function/constructor call in C#

Tags: c#, ambiguous-call

The following code causes a compiler error, as it is ambiguous call but the problem if we use `object` instead of `ArrayList` no error happens and the `string` version works fine; Do you have an explanation for that?

```
class A
{
    public A(string x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("string");
    }
    public A(ArrayList x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ArrayList");
    }

}
    static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            A o = new A(null);
        }
```

Comment: I'm sure someone will post a better explanation than I could, but needless to say, you should probably avoid this pattern and implement a default constructor.  Oh wait, I said it...

Comment: What version of .NET do you use? Because if you use 2.0 or over, you could use an IList<T> or whatever other collection that best fits your situation? Implementing a default constructor might also help.

Comment: @Will Marcouiller: .Net 3.5 but I wonder about the behavior itself this is an example

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reason your code works fine if you change the constructor that takes an `ArrayList` to take an `object` is that the C# compiler will pick the most specific type applicable. In the case of `string`/`object`, `string` actually *derives* from `object` and is therefore "more specific" and will be inferred by the compiler. With `string` versus `ArrayList`, it's apples and oranges: either can be null, but neither is more "specific" than the other.

Comment: +1 beat me to the explanation. Your answer is the only one that answers the actual question.

Comment: Line of the day : *it's apples and oranges: either can be null, but neither is more "specific" than the other.* :)

Comment: @TheMachineCharmer: What, you've never eaten a null apple? They're delicious.

Comment: NO. There were only 4 null apples. And they were all consumed by by Adam,Isaac Newton,Steve Jobs and you! (chronologically)  :) lol

Answer (score 4):

I could be wrong, but I think the reason it works when you change ArrayList to object is because string inherits from object and it decides to use the more specific string version.  When it's string and ArrayList it doesn't know which one to use.

Answer (score 3):

`null` could represent either a `string`, or an `ArrayList`. There's no information there is to which version of the method (in this case a constructor) you meant.

You can force it to use a specific one by casting:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A o = new A((string)null);
    }
```

...or alternately implementing a constructor that behaves as you want (that takes no parameter)

Comment: An `object` could be null too, but the OP indicated that changing `ArrayList` to `object` resolves the issue; so this isn't the whole picture. The real issue is that in this case, neither type will "win" in the eyes of the compiler because one does not inherit from the other. In the case of `string` vs. `object`, `string` wins out because it derives from `object` and is therefore more specific.

Comment: What about using object, you did not answer me

Answer (score 2):

you can tackle this situation by using *default* keyword like, and the code will be:

```
A o = new A(default(ArrayList));
```

Or

```
A o = new A(default(string));
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Of course it's ambiguous: `null` could be either a `string` or an `ArrayList`. You'll need to qualify it, like `(string) null`.
2. Did you know that `ArrayList` is deprecated? You should use one of the generic collection types instead

Comment: For the ArrayList, it depends on the version of the Framework he uses, I guess. But good point for the `null` ambiguity.

Comment: @Will: if he's still using .NET 1.1, I'd tell him that .NET 1.1 has been deprecated.

Comment: Hehehe... Right! =) But sometimes one has to deal with administrative decisions. If it's not broken, don't fix it! But yet, I get your point anyway. =)

Comment: I putted ArrayList as an example I am using .Net 3.5

Comment: `ArrayList` is a class you should no longer use. The direct replacement is `List<object>`.

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList` and `string` are both [**`nullable`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) types. That confuses compiler.

If you have two constructors say one that takes nullable type e.g. `ArrayList` and other that takes `non-nullable` type e.g. `int`. The code *will compile* and choose the constructor with `nullable` type.

But if you have more that one constructor that takes `nullable` type then like [@Dan Tao](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865415/ambiguous-function-constructor-call-in-c/2865465#2865465) said *it's apples and oranges: either can be null, but neither is more "specific" than the other.*

for example:

```
class A
{
    public A(int x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("string");
    }
    public A(ArrayList x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ArrayList");
    }

}
```

This code compiles
    but if you change `public A(int x)t` to `public A(int? x)` it will NOT.

Comment: It's not really to do with them being nullable\reference types, but rather that there is no 'best' option to choose between string and ArrayList. If you had a function with an overload taking a Stream, and one taking a MemoryStream and called it with null then the compiler would be able to resolve it.

Comment: @Lee Thanks! But could you please explain how compiler resolves it in that case?

Comment: This post from Eric Lippert explains overload resolution better than me - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856023/c-method-generic-params-parameter-bug/2858949#2858949.